# How to find out how many days a month has and save it in a variable

Tags: python, datetime

I have been struggling lately to find out how many days a month has and save them in a var.So far my progress is:

```
import calendar

days_of_month = calendar.monthrange(2018,2)
```

However this brings up `(3,28)`.I only want the number 28.What can i do to save only 28 in a var ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(3, 28)` is a tuple, to get the second value, you just need index:

```
days_of_month = calendar.monthrange(2018,2)[1]
```

Note that index starts from 0, thus second index is 1.

Comment: I know its a tuple.I tried using it like this:     days = days_of_month[4:6] , tried many numbers too but didn't work either.I will go study how tuples work.Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way i can accmplish it without calendar library ? I really must not use this library for that program.

Comment: Simply write a tuple by yourself. Take special care of February.